# What happens when you use git svn clone without any options?

Tags: git, svn

The documentation on [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) states that you can either provide the `-s` flag to indicate that your Subversion repository uses the standard layout (`trunk`, `branches`, `tags`), or that you can specify `-T`, `-b`, and `-t` to customize those paths.

What happens if I omit all of those flags, and just say

```
$ git svn clone <url>
```

?

I'm somewhat afraid to simply try it out, because I don't want to do any harm to the Subversion repository accidentally.

Any help?

Comment: Make a new repository to test with and try it on that one?

Comment: Yes, of course I can do that, but this means I have to setup a repo, add some commits, create some branches and tags, and so on… I just thought that it might be easier to ask someone who has experience with this.